# Assign certain integer a value depending on string value in c#

Tags: c#

Suppose I have 3 integers all declared as

```
int Y = 0;
int N = 0;
int U = 0;
```

From there I grab 2 values from a stored procedure (one string and 1 integer). 
 The string returns either Y,N,U 
The integer returns a count of the people attending.

```
string test = dr["ATTEND_CDE"].ToString();
int test2 = int.Parse(dr["COUNT"].ToString());
```

Is there a better way to assign the corresponding integer the count other than:

```
if (test == "Y")
{
    Y = test2;
}
else if (test == "N")
{
    N = test2;
}
else if (test == "U")
{
    U = test2;
}
```

Comment: Just a side note: get rid of those "test" variable names before it's too late, they make the code harder to understand.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you really have here is a mapping between a `string` ("Y", "N", or "U") and an `int`.

This is a perfect use case for a `Dictionary` (C# 6 syntax follows):

```
Dictionary<string, int> myValues = new Dictionary<string, int>()
{
    ["Y"] = 0,
    ["N"] = 0,
    ["U"] = 0
};

//usage
myValues[stringFromDatabase] = valueFromDatabase;
```

Note that this will throw (which is probably what you want) if the value from the database is junk.

Comment: You can do that in C# 3 too: `{ "Y", 0 },`

Comment: @SLaks Yes, but since I used the C# 6 form (with the index notation) I wanted to call that out. The C# 3 syntax is also valid of course.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfect and looks a lot better than an if statement

Comment: @BringQBasicBack FWIW, its more efficient (O(1) vs (O(n)) too (not that you would notice unless there was a lot of these, but still....)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a switch statement on strings. So for your example above,

```
switch(test)
{
    case "Y": Y = test2; break;
    case "N": N = test2; break;
    case "U": U = test2; break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you store `Y`, `N`, `U` as properties in a class then you can work with

- Data contracts (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms733127%28v=VS.110%29.aspx)
- an ORM framework ([Best ORM to use with C# 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187928/best-orm-to-use-with-c-sharp-4-0))
- automatic JSON deserialization  ([Deserializing JSON to .NET object using Newtonsoft (or LINQ to JSON maybe?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749639/deserializing-json-to-net-object-using-newtonsoft-or-linq-to-json-maybe))
- automatic XML deserialization (http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/csharp/xmlserializer-example.htm)

If you use c# 6.0 then you can at least do something like

```
if(test.equals(nameof(y)))
{
     //...
}
```